# XNamespace as additional attribute, why

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xattribute, xnamespace

I want to achieve this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>    
    <add key="WriteToLogFile" value="true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    <add key="SendErrorEmail" value="false" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />    
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Here is my c# code:

```
var items = GetItems();
XNamespace xdtNamespace = "xdt";

XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("configuration", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xdt", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"),
new XElement("appSettings", from item in items
    select new XElement("add",
        new XAttribute("key", item.Key),
        new XAttribute("value", item.Value),
        new XAttribute(xdtNamespace + "Transform", "SetAttributes(value)"),
        new XAttribute(xdtNamespace + "Locator", "Match(name)")))));

doc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);                
doc.Save("Test.xml");
```

Output for my c# code is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>   
    <add key="WriteToLogFile" value="true" p4:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" p4:Locator="Match(name)" xmlns:p4="xdt" />
    <add key="SendErrorEmail" value="false" p4:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" p4:Locator="Match(name)" xmlns:p4="xdt" />    
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, for each element there is an extra attribute **xmlns:p4="xdt"**.
And attributes Transform and Locator are prefixed with **p4** instead of **xdt**.
Why is it this happening?

I already read msdn documentation related to xml namespaces (and few other similar articles), but frankly speaking it is quite confusing, I didn't find anything helpful.

Are there any *good* articles, which explain in a nutshell my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing a namespace alias (which you want to be `xdt`) with the namespace URI. You want to put the elements in the right namespace (by URI) but specify an `xmlns` attribute in the root element with the alias you want:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XNamespace xdt = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform";

        XDocument doc = new XDocument(
            new XElement("configuration",
                new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xdt", xdt.NamespaceName),
                new XElement("appSettings",
                    new XElement("add",
                        new XAttribute("key", "WriteToLogFile"),
                        new XAttribute("value", true),
                        new XAttribute(xdt + "Transform", "SetAttributes(value)"),
                        new XAttribute(xdt + "Locator", "Match(name)")
                    )
                )
            )
        );
        Console.WriteLine(doc);
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WriteToLogFile" value="true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```